# Dynamic children navigation in React.js (propagating events and properties)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One thing I'm still struggling with in React.js is the proper way to handle child event and property propagation. There are many examples of this being done already, but the implementations are always vastly different. Surely, there is a "right way" to do it...

The task is to create a "Nav" component which is made up of "NavItem" components. Below is the code that I am expecting to work, but it doesn't. The comments explain where I'm having issues. Please advise on the best solution and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

**Nav.jsx**

```
var Nav = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        active:         React.PropTypes.string,
        onSelect:       React.PropTypes.func
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            active: this.props.active
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return this.transferPropsTo(
            <nav>
                {this.props.children.map(this.renderChild)}
            </nav>
        );
    },
    renderChild: function (child, i) {
        // Here I want to generate a unique 'key' property for each child as well
        // as define a custom onSelect method which will tell the "Nav" component which is
        // the active key.
        return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, {
            // Here I want to use the 'active' property of the Nav component to drive the
            // the 'active' property of the child.
            active: this.state.active === i ? true, false,
            key: i,
            onSelect: this.handleSelect
        });
    },
    handleSelect: function (event, component) {
        // PROBLEM: Here I want to get the 'key' property of the child. But there seems to be
        // no way to do this.
        var _child_key_ = 'impossible'; 
        this.setState({active: _child_key_});
    }
});
```

**NavItem.jsx**

```
var NavItem = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        active:     React.PropTypes.string,
        onSelect:   React.PropTypes.func
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            active: this.props.active
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return this.transferPropsTo(
            <a className="{this.state.active ? 'active' : ''}" onClick={this.handleSelect}>
                {this.props.label}
            </a>
        );
    },
    handleSelect: function (event, component) {
        // Propagate the event up to the parent event property.
        if (this.props.handleSelect) this.props.handleSelect(event, component);
    }
});
```

**MyApp.jsx**

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Nav>
                <NavItem label="Home" />
                <NavItem label="Page1" />
                <NavItem label="Page2" />
            </Nav>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(new App(), document.body)
```

Comment: There's no real reason, at least in this example, why you can't just pass a function as a property called `onClick` to your `NavItem` and have the `NavItem`'s `onClick` handler check if it exists (and is a func) and then call it with the event as first arg and  `this.props.key` as a 2nd argument.  The result being that your `Nav` indirectly handles the click even on the `<a>` tag in your `NavItem`

Comment: In your use case, you don't need to clone the children with `cloneWithProps` since you are just passing props.

Comment: I need to generate a new 'active' prop and a new 'key' prop for each child. The only way I found to be able to pass that into children is to use cloneWithProps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the most sane way.

```
var Nav = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        active:         React.PropTypes.string,
        onSelect:       React.PropTypes.func
    },

    // no state
    //getInitialState: function () {},

    render: function () {
        // use React.Children.map because children is opaque
        return this.transferPropsTo(
            <nav>
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.renderChild)}
            </nav>
        );
    },
    renderChild: function (child, i) {
        return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, {
            // use the prop, not state
            active: this.props.active === i,
            key: i,

            // let the parent decide how to handle the data change
            // give it the clicked index
            onSelect: this.props.onSelect.bind(null, i)
        });
    }
});
```

```
var NavItem = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        // it's a boolean
        active:     React.PropTypes.bool,
        onSelect:   React.PropTypes.func
    },
    // again, no state
    //getInitialState: function () {},

    render: function () {
        // just pass the onSelect handler in directly
        // let the parent handle it
        return this.transferPropsTo(
            <a className={this.props.active ? 'active' : ''} 
               onClick={this.props.onSelect}>
                {this.props.label}
            </a>
        );
    }
});
```

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){ return {active: 0} },

    handleSelect: function(i){ this.setState({active: i}) },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <Nav onSelect={this.handleSelect} active={this.state.active}>
                <NavItem label="Home" />
                <NavItem label="Page1" />
                <NavItem label="Page2" />
            </Nav>
        );
    }
});
```